# Root element is missing in Biztalk Server when sending message to port

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, biztalk, biztalk-2010

My scenario seems quite simple:

We have a file with some format, **myfileddmmyyhhss.txt**, and inside the file we have something like this:

```
H|3      |20110607235508
V|M006      |HAB8753   |NY|PAS|20151123|232155|M||
V|M006      |HAB8752   |NY|PAS|20151123|232155|M||
V|M006      |HAB8751   |NY|PAS|20151123|232155|M||
T|3      |20110607235508
```

Also using the sql adapter we generated a schema for executing a stored procedure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
- <xs:schema xmlns="http://SqlAdapterFile" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://SqlAdapterFile" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
- <xs:annotation>
- <xs:appinfo>
  <msbtssql:sqlScript value="exec [sp_insertFile] @fileName=" "" xmlns:msbtssql="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
- <xs:element name="fileRequest">
+ <xs:annotation>
- <xs:appinfo>
- <properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003">
  <property distinguished="true" xpath="/*[local-name()='fileRequest' and namespace-uri()='http://SqlAdapterFile']/*[local-name()='sp_insertFile' and namespace-uri()='http://SqlAdapterFile']/@*[local-name()='fileName' and namespace-uri()='']" /> 
  </properties>
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
+ <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
- <xs:element name="sp_insertFile">
- <xs:complexType>
  <xs:attribute name="fileName" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
- <xs:element name="fileResponse">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Success" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

Using the flat file schema wizard we created the schema which is not relevant for this question.  Now we need to create a message that should be redirected to a send port, the message only has a child element with the filename, we created a map, but there is no real mapping because we are using a constant. As you can see there is no mapping between fields, we used the value property to set a fixed value, to see if we could make this works.  The right side schema is the one pasted above.

[image]

However we have this error, all we need is an XML in the send location with the hard coded filename on it.

> xlang/s engine event log entry: Uncaught exception (see the 'inner
>   exception' below) has suspended an instance of service
>   'BizTalkNyCase.BizTalk_Orchestration1(ac1a86a0-9cc1-4850-d5f1-236b0663b4da)'.
>   The service instance will remain suspended until administratively
>   resumed or terminated.  If resumed the instance will continue from its
>   last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
>   InstanceId: db35db6f-f14d-44ca-bea7-a3f747b550d5 Shape name: Send_2
>   ShapeId: 81933178-7b3c-49c2-a0b1-0cce3d4aa6ec Exception thrown from:
>   segment 1, progress 16 Inner exception: Root element is missing.
>            Exception type: XmlException Source: System.Xml Target Site: Void Throw(System.Exception) The following is a stack trace that
>   identifies the location where the exception occured

Comment: 1) When posting a schema, don't post it as viewed in a browser, as that adds +s and -s in front of nodes.   2) Are you still using the deprecated SQL adapter rather than the WCF-SQL adapter?  The schema seems to indicate that  3) Where have you put that map? It looks like you have it in the Orchestration.  4) Have you tested the map in Visual Studio?  What does the output look like?  5) What does the message look like in the suspended Orchestration after the map?

Comment: I've found that when I get this error, it's usually related to a missing/unexpected namespace somewhere. I have to agree with @Dijkgraaf test the map, look at the output, look at the suspended message and check to see what namespace is there.

Comment: Definitely move to the WCF-SQL adapter if possible.

Comment: +1 for testing the map. Validating the btm file in visual studio to take a look at the XSLT might also be a good place to find errors.